# How to retrieve user logged on by reading computer name from database?

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I am very new to powershell and have this script that will ping every computer from a database server.
I am using MySQL (yes I know most people use MSSQL with powershell but in my case I have to use MySQL).

The ping works perfectly fine, how can I retrieve USERNAME for every computer that pings succesfully?

Thanks in advance!

Below is my code:

```
#ping the computers from the database to verify if it is online/offline 
 #Create a command object
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand;
$command.Connection = $connection

# $command = $connection.CreateCommand() #ERROR

#call procedure to execute the command
$command.CommandText = "SELECT w.ws FROM
                        sandbox_maesc4.coordinates c
                        INNER JOIN
                        softphone_materials_updater.workstations w
                        ON c.station_number = w.pod";

#Execute the Command by reading each row
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader();
#Read values from database
$workstation_list = $( while ($reader.Read() ){
                    $reader.GetValue(0) 
                })
   #close reader                     
$reader.Close()


#ping each computer if online, obtain username logged in only
foreach($pc_db in $workstation_list){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc_db -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
     #HERE IS THE CODE, I JUST WANT TO RETRIEVE USERNAME THAT'S LOGGED ON!    
     Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $pc_db -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$pc_db is Offline" -ForegroundColor Red
    }


}#end for each loop  
$connection.Close()
}#end ping_test function

db_conn #execute function
```

Comment: you mean get the name of whoever's logged in on the machine you're pinging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the username of the current logged on user, you can reference the `Win32_ComputerSystem` WMI object which has a `username` parameter containing the current logged-in user:

```
Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $pc_db -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
```

Comment: Man you are fast :) in PowerShell v3 `Get-WMIObject` is superseded and Get-CimInstance should be used

Comment: True, however I believe WMI has the advantage of being fully compatible with legacy systems (XP, 2003, etc.)...not that those systems should ideally be in a prod environment by now.

Comment: i agree for old systems wmi is the way to go, also agree with the second part

Comment: As for speed - combine caffeine with a PowerShell-centric day and there's your answer :)

Comment: @Kohlbrr hey I tested it and gives me this error ( I put it inside my IF statement where I ping each computer): **Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null va
lue.** whats going on?

Comment: Change the command to `Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $pc_db -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Username` and let me know if the "Username" property is populated / the command executes successfully.

Comment: Run `Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $pc_db -Class Win32_ComputerSystem` and see if it returns something (disregard me, i´ll leave this to you @Kohlbrr :))

Comment: @Kohlbrr it gives me this long output, some of  them have usernames and others dont: **__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_ComputerSystem
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
UserName         :**

Comment: @Kohlbrr If I removed **-ExpandProperty** from the answer that you gave me it stops showing **"obj" is null"**. However, it skips lines in blank spaces and gives me the usernames. I'm confused

Comment: Can you give an example of the output? Does the command successfully return any usernames?

Comment: @Kohlbrr If I use the following command **Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $pc_db -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username** It gives me this output: **Username                                                                                                                                
--------                                                                                                                                  
callcentre\oxgor** which oxgor is the username but at moments it will give me this error : **Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable** how can I avoid it?

Comment: @mario "RPC server is unavailable" is usually a firewall problem on the remote machine. are you requesting the object from the same computer that returned output before?

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry im not understanding your question? I tried doing TRY-CATCH but still shows up

Comment: He's asking if there are some computers that consistently give the username, and others that consistently throw an RPC error - specifically that a computer doesn't return a username sometimes and an RPC error at other times.

Comment: @Paul It only throws an RPC error once. The other times it will either show me the usernames that are logged on on those computers and the others will just return me an empty username with the computer name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $pc_db -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username
```

This should return the currently active user

Comment: Hey I tested it and gives me this error : **The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again** I put it inside my IF statement where I ping each computer.. whats going on?

Comment: please post the output of $psversiontable, i guess you are running powershell v2. if this is the case use Get-WmiObject like Kohlbrr suggests

Comment: I updated my code so you can see where exactly I put it, I commented it out because Im comparing both answers

Comment: $psversiontable: **CLRVersion  2.0.50727.5485    BuildVersion  6.1.7601.17514 
PSVersion     2.0                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion    2.0                                                                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0}                                                                                               
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1                                                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion  2.1**

Comment: I was right, you are using V2. Get-CimInstance is a V3 cmdlet. Please remove the powershell v3 tag from your question